# iOS7 UIWebivew Youtube MPMediaPlayer not working

Tags: uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios7

I need to play a video within an UIWebiview which comes from youtube. 
Everything was working fine on older devices (`5.1+`)

Unfortunately on `iOS7` the video is not playing. It starts `loading` but it'll never start playing. Even if the video has fully been loaded. Only if you stop and press play manually the video starts playing.

Here's some code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(!self.viewMoviePlayerView.superview) {
        [self.viewMediaContentContainer addSubview:self.viewMoviePlayerView];
    }
    self.viewMoviePlayerView.isScrollingEnabled = NO;

    [self.viewMoviePlayerView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/", self.currentSelectedItem.guid]]]];
...
}
```

Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

Autoplay is not allowed on recent versions of iOS. You don't suppose to programmatically start downloading data that could cause a cost to the user. I found a way but it's a little tricky:

- Show an html string in stead of an url

  ```
  [webview loadHTMLString:<html> baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
  ```
- The html needs to be an embed player:

  ```
  <html>
  <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
          ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerID',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady, onStateChange:onPlayerStateChange}});
       }
    function onPlayerReady(a){ a.target.playVideo(); }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
       if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
          event.target.playVideo();
       }
    }
    </script>
    <iframe id='playerID' type='text/html' width='320' height='240'
       src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1" frameborder='0'></iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

  this works fine because the javascript in the iframe API it forces the player to start playing once it loads and every time it starts buffering. I strongly suggest you to [read about the youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)
- Put your video id in the embed and thats it!